# Check if application was started through Toast Notification panel click

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

Is it possible to check whether the application was started when the user received the Toast Notification and clicked it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the page URL (which opens when the Toast is tapped), add a query string. For example:

```
"<wp:Param>/ToastPage.xaml?NavigatedFrom=FromToast</wp:Param>"
```

Then, in your `ToastPage.xaml`'s `OnNavigatedTo` method, you can check for the query string

```
string navFrom= "";

NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("NavigatedFrom", out navFrom);
```

Here, `navFrom` will store the value `FromToast` if it came from toast, otherwise it will either store something else if you have other query string values or remain as `""`.